# Are there airlines offering possibility of flight on board with bigger dog like labrador? (Europe-USA flights)

Tags: dogs, travel

I am aware that this is possible to travel with smaller dogs in pet cage on board, but mostly, as far I googled topic for now, for bigger dogs like e.g. labrador retriever it is impossible to take dog on board, so they must travel in the Luggage Compartment, what must be an extremely traumatic experience for them.

So the question: Are there airlines offering possibility of flight on board with bigger dog like labrador on intercontinental flights like USA-Europe?

Comment: Don't forget to check the quarantine regulations for your destination country.

Answer (score 3):

> OP: "they must travel in the Luggage Compartment, what must be an extremely traumatic experience for them."

This assumption that the cargo area is a bad place for dogs is simply not true. Usually it is the humans who experience anxiety from not knowing how their dog is doing. The cargo area is always pressurized along with the rest of the plane. Usually it is comfortably warm as well; just ask to be sure.

Make sure the dog is used to the crate and has used it many times before the trip. I would suggest using it in the house and in the back of your van or car. If the dog is comfortable (not anxious) with the crate then the cargo area will be fine.

> https://www.petrelocation.com/blog/post/five-common-misconceptions-about-pet-travel
>   Many air travelers have trouble with the idea of separating from their pets and placing them in the cargo area, when in fact this part of the plane is actually preferable in many ways. Temperature and pressure-controlled and offering less commotion and confusing noise than the cabin, the cargo hold of a plane that's operated by a pet-friendly airline generally offers a better flying experience for pets.

I'm not affiliated with Pet Relocation but I found their blog posts on transporting large dogs to be really helpful.

https://www.petrelocation.com/dogs/transporting-large-dogs
https://www.petrelocation.com/blog/post/facts-about-pet-transport-safety
https://www.petrelocation.com/blog/post/pet-cargo-myths-and-facts

Comment: thanks for the input! I agree this may be misconception but sometimes things are a bit counterintuitive ;)

Answer (score 2):

intresting quote from lufthansa:

> "If you have booked a flight to/from the USA, there is also the option
>   of transporting an ESAN dog (emotional support animal) in the aircraft
>   cabin free of charge. You will require confirmation from your doctor
>   that you require an assistance dog. Please note that the dog’s
>   suitability for transport in the aircraft cabin may be checked."

http://www.lufthansa.com/de/en/Travel-preparations-for-passengers-with-special-needs#ancAbT6

ESAN defintion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotional_support_animal
I am afraid ESAN as something legaly defined functions only in the USA.